# How to make Ribbon gallery in Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, ribbon, delphi-xe2

I am biting my way through the Ribbon and I got to yet another problem - how do I make dropdown menu, dropdown gallery or just a gallery? I will show you what I mean in screenshots; this question might a bit general, but I think this is as close as I can get.

---

**Dropdown gallery:**
[image: This is a dropdown gallery]

I can't figure out how to create a gallery that would show on click at all. Even if it did, how do I fill in the pictures/buttons?

---

**Gallery:**
[image]

Same as above. No luck here.

---

I want to make a color selection galleries (both dropdown and 'normal') and this seems to be the best way - I don't want a button that would just open a ColorDialog on clicking.

Thanks for your help

- I would post some code, but I don't see any relevant I could provide, since this is more like a GUI-related problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't figured out how to do it, but I found this wonderful tool for Delphi - it works without problems so far. It is a little tricky to get used to, but it works pretty logically. Plus it has everything I can think of.

Link: http://www.bilsen.com/windowsribbon/index.shtml
(Windows Ribbon Framework for Delphi)

Comment: What about the licensing from Microsoft? Do I need to obtain a license from them to use the Ribbon UI?

Comment: Check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx - all you have to do is accept their terms (Last paragraph-yellow line)

Comment: @Magicmaster: AFAIK the Office UI license (if it's valid at all) doesn't apply to the Ribbon Framework - see [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/windowsribbondevelopment/thread/b43aa9cc-0aac-44b5-afb9-af66a9997225).

Comment: Oh. Sorry then, your link seems to be legit, since it's answered by a MS employee. Thank for correcting me

Comment: I found [a better source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx): "Use of the Scenic Ribbon implementation is governed by the Microsoft Windows SDK EULA and does not require a developer to accept the terms of the Office UI license on this site."